# Fix Python3 upgrade in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, python, python3

I have upgraded python3 in Ubuntu 16.04 from the default version to 3.6.3. But, it does not work fine. For instance, when I run "import matplotlib", it complains:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

And, when I run `sudo apt install python3-matplotlib`, it tells me:

```
python3-matplotlib is already the newest version (1.5.1-1ubuntu1).
```

I tried this idea, but apparently it didn't help: I had Ubuntu 14.04, I upgraded python3. I had the same issue with matplotlib. I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Still had this issue. Used Resetter application, and did a complete package and user reset. The issue is still there.

Some information:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.3

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.5 /etc/python3 /etc/python3.5 /usr/local/bin/python3.4-config /usr/local/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/local/bin/python3.6m /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3.4m-config /usr/local/bin/python3.4 /usr/local/bin/python3.4m /usr/local/bin/python3.6-config /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/include/python3.5m /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

Edit1: Does `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` restore python3 to the system's default?

Comment: DO NOT change the system-provided Python2 and Python3. Essential system services rely upon the provided versions. Restore the stock Ubuntu packages.

Comment: @user535733 How can I  restore the stock Ubuntu packages? I tried Resetter for this purpose, but it didn't help.

Comment: How did you upgrade them? We need to know the exact process you followed.

Answer (score 3):

The version of Python that Ubuntu ships with is still there, it just doesn't have priority in your path, because `/usr/local/bin/` trumps `/usr/bin/`. And that's poisoning your entire system.

The best option at this point is **do the opposite of what you did to create `/usr/local/bin/python3`**. We don't have any detail on what's happened here so if that's a symlink you've created, delete it, or if it's a real binary you've compiled or extracted, take the appropriate action.

If you want Python 3.6, install it in a different environment. Don't attempt to replace the system version. Ubuntu needs its version of Python to do Ubuntuey things. There are tools like virtualenv that allow you to map `python` and `python3` to whatever version you like, and install Python packages without breaking Ubuntu's.

If you want a supported version of Python 3.6, it's available in 17.10, though you'll need to upgrade Ubuntu again in ~9 months.